# BG96 LwM2M Configuration

Tags: arduino, network-protocols, at-command, cellular-network, quectel

I am trying to use the already implemented LWM2M protocol on bg96 from Quectel, to create a client and connect it to Leshan server. I know on the firmware release of "BG96MAR02A07M1G" LWM2M protocol is implemented but I am facing problems while configuring it. According to the user guide provided by Quectel, the AT commands configure some files in Embedded File system and after reboot the LWM2M is suppose to run automatically. The sequence of `AT` commands I have used is as follows:

```
AT+QLWM2M="select",0

AT+QLWM2M="enable",1

AT+QLWM2M="bootstrap",1,"coap://leshan.eclipse.org:5683"

AT+QLWM2M="bootstrap",2,"300"

AT+QLWM2M="bootstrap",3,"0"

AT+QLWM2M="bootstrap",4,"3"

AT+QLWM2M="qcli_en",1

AT+QLWM2M="apn","zonginternet"

AT+QLWM2M="endpoint",4,4

AT+QLWM2M="reset"
```

After this I restart my module and I should receive some information on debug port like this:

```
Net: Net Registered
dss_netapp: DSS_NetApp Registered
LwM2M_EXT: LwM2M_EXT Registered
Command List:
Commands:
1. Help
2. Exit
Subgroups:
3. Net
4. dss_netapp
5. LwM2M_EXT
> LwM2M: CLI registered
LwM2M: LwM2M_LOG:Carrier type = 0
LwM2M:
LwM2M: REG EP NAME = 4
LwM2M:
LwM2M: BOOTSTRAP EP NAME = 7
```

But I am not getting anything on debug port. Keep one thing in mind: before executing all these `AT` commands related to LWM2M my module is already connected to internet. Does anybody has any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

To all the people who have have this problem, try using the DBG_UART pins available on your development board instead of connecting the terminal to Debug port available on USB. I was able to connect my device as a client and also could receive messages on debug port.
P.S: You will need USB to TTL bridge while reading values from external pins.